# How to Stop Selenium Standalone Server from Running Mocha/Chai/WebdriverIO Tests Every Time I Save a Change?

Tags: selenium, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io, isparta

I am currently using a testing framework with Mocha, Chai, and WebdriverIO. As it stands, the Selenium Standalone Server runs the full test suite whenever I save a change to the spec file. I want to disable this and only run the test suite when I enter the command to do so in the terminal. This command currently works, but because the tests are also being run automatically on save, sometimes multiple identical tests run concurrently, causing errors.

How do I stop the Selenium Standalone Server from auto-running tests?

**Update:** As a commenter requested, here is my *package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "react-slingshot",
  "version": "5.0.0",
  "description": "Starter kit for creating apps with React and Redux",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node tools/nodeVersionCheck.js",
    "setup": "node tools/setup/setupMessage.js && npm install && node tools/setup/setup.js",
    "start-message": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "prestart": "npm-run-all --parallel start-message remove-dist",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "open:dist": "babel-node tools/distServer.js",
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src tools --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "rimraf ./dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean-dist && npm run lint && npm run test",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist",
    "build-prod": "babel-node tools/build.js",
    "test": "mocha tools/testSetup.js \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.spec.js\" --reporter progress",
    "test:cover": "babel-node node_modules/isparta/bin/isparta cover --root src --report html node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --require ./tools/testSetup.js \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.spec.js\" --reporter progress",
    "test:cover:travis": "babel-node node_modules/isparta/bin/isparta cover --root src --report lcovonly _mocha -- --require ./tools/testSetup.js \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.spec.js\" && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "open:cover": "npm run test:cover && open coverage/index.html",
    "analyze-bundle": "babel-node ./tools/analyzeBundle.js",
    "scp-upload": "node tools/deployToRemote",
    "deploy": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run scp-upload"
  },
  "author": "Cory House",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.15.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "3.1.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "j-toker": "0.0.10-beta3",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "less": "2.7.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.2",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0",
    "pingpp-js": "2.1.5",
    "postcss-strip-inline-comments": "0.1.5",
    "qrcode.react": "0.6.1",
    "react": "15.3.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.30.8",
    "react-bootstrap-button-loader": "1.0.8",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "5.0.1",
    "react-burger-menu": "1.10.14",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "0.1.3",
    "react-country-region-selector": "1.0.4",
    "react-document-meta": "2.1.1",
    "react-dom": "15.3.2",
    "react-dropzone": "3.13.1",
    "react-ga": "2.1.2",
    "react-gravatar": "2.6.1",
    "react-lazyload": "2.2.7",
    "react-masonry-component": "5.0.3",
    "react-pager": "1.2.1",
    "react-progress-button": "5.0.4",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-responsive": "1.3.0",
    "react-router": "3.0.5",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "0.23.1",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.6",
    "react-scroll": "1.5.2",
    "react-share": "1.12.1",
    "react-sidebar": "2.3.0",
    "react-slick": "0.15.0",
    "react-svg": "2.1.19",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "6.6.3",
    "redux-promise": "0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
    "redux-ui": "0.0.15",
    "scp2": "0.5.0",
    "slick-carousel": "1.6.0",
    "svg-injector": "1.1.3",
    "universal-cookie": "2.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "3.5.1",
    "autoprefixer": "6.5.1",
    "babel-cli": "6.16.0",
    "babel-core": "6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.2.11",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.2.10",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-latest": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.16.0",
    "babel-register": "6.16.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "browser-sync": "2.17.5",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "0.3.2",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "coveralls": "2.11.14",
    "cross-env": "3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "2.5.1",
    "eslint": "3.8.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-watch": "2.1.14",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.0",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "1.4.4",
    "isparta": "4.0.0",
    "istanbul": "0.4.4",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "mocha": "3.1.2",
    "mockdate": "1.0.4",
    "node-sass": "3.10.1",
    "npm-run-all": "3.1.1",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "postcss-cssnext": "3.0.2",
    "postcss-import": "10.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "postcss-scss": "1.0.2",
    "postcss-strip-inline-comments": "0.1.5",
    "postcss-url": "7.1.0",
    "precss": "2.0.0",
    "prompt": "1.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.3.2",
    "react-truncate": "2.1.0",
    "redux-devtools": "3.3.1",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.4",
    "replace": "0.3.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "1.6.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "s3-deploy": "0.7.3",
    "sass-loader": "4.0.2",
    "sinon": "1.17.6",
    "sinon-chai": "2.8.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "svg-url-loader": "2.1.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "0.5.11",
    "webdriverio": "4.8.0",
    "webpack": "3.5.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "1.5.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.8.4",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.13.0",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reactjs",
    "react-router",
    "hot",
    "reload",
    "hmr",
    "live",
    "edit",
    "webpack",
    "redux",
    "flux",
    "boilerplate",
    "starter"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot"
  }
}
```

**Update 2:** The output of `ps aux | grep npm`:

```
cxk280            3750   0.0  0.9  3102016  37076 s003  S+    8:31PM   0:01.01 npm   
cxk280            3716   0.0  0.7  3096668  30752 s003  S+    8:31PM   0:01.14 node /Users/cxk280/code/my_directory/node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec npm run babel-node
cxk280            3715   0.0  0.6  3102016  23348 s003  S+    8:31PM   0:00.92 npm  
cxk280            3383   0.0  0.6  3102016  23240 s001  S+    8:30PM   0:00.97 npm     
cxk280            3382   0.0  0.5  3102016  22540 s001  S+    8:30PM   0:00.97 npm     
cxk280            3379   0.0  0.5  3102016  22536 s001  S+    8:30PM   0:01.00 npm   
cxk280            3378   0.0  0.6  3102016  23236 s001  S+    8:30PM   0:01.00 npm   
cxk280            3377   0.0  0.6  3102056  23236 s001  S+    8:30PM   0:01.01 npm   
cxk280            3375   0.0  0.4  3081244  14712 s001  S+    8:30PM   0:00.66 node /Users/cxk280/code/my_directory/node_modules/.bin/npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch
cxk280            3122   0.0  0.6  3102528  23244 s001  S+    8:30PM   0:00.76 npm  
cxk280            4520   0.0  0.0  2423384    232 s006  R+    8:32PM   0:00.00 grep npm
```

Comment: Post your package.json

Comment: I have updated my original post with the *package.json*.

Comment: Also please add output of `ps aux | grep npm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `npm start` is run, it runs the following command:

```
npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch
```

The `test:watch` is what is likely triggering your test suite to run again.

If you want to avoid that, just run `npm run open:src` to start your server, then `npm test` to run your test.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Do you have any idea why the `npm start` script might be triggered by merely saving a change to one of the files?